# Does PHP scanf behave differently with %f versus %lf?

Tags: php

Are these two lines equivalent? Is one recommended over the other? How about `%d` and `%ld`?

```
fscanf( $f, "%f", $value );
fscanf( $f, "%lf", $value );
```

Comment: The documentation at https://www.php.net/fscanf does not contain any `l` specifier

Comment: @NicoHaase correct, which is why I was curious – I see some code using it and others not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I [read their source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/scanf.c#L717) right, the `l` modifier is simply ignored, so there shouldn't be any difference, and the recommended version should be *without* the `l`, which is also not found in the official documentation.

Modifiers are also ignored in `sprintf`.

Comment: Thanks. Source code verifies there is no functional difference. The secondary question is more opinion-based, but do you think it would be a good idea to keep the size specifier when reading potentially large numbers simply to keep it consistent with other language use?

Comment: Not really. If PHP one day decided to throw errors for every unused specifiers, now you would have a huge broken codebase. I would - at most - add a comment, or name the variables in a sensible way.